# Is numpy.random.choice with replacement equivalent to multinomial sampling for a single trial?

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics, multinomial

I understand that strictly on concept, they are different. But in a single trial (or experiment) for `numpy.random.multinomial`, is it sampling the same way as `numpy.random.choice` though giving a different view of the output?

For example:

```
>> np.random.choice(6, size=6, replace=True, p=[1/6.]*6)
>> array([2, 0, 4, 2, 5, 4])
```

Output gives the identity of what was picked in the array `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`

and

```
>> np.random.multinomial(1, [1/6.]*6, size=6)
>> array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
          [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Output gives the number of times each choice was picked, but since it was limited to 1 trial, it can also be summarized as `[2,5,3,3,4,1]` from choices `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: For a single trial, replacement doesn't even matter. Also - `[2,5,3,3,4,0]` - i.e. 0 in the end, not 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are effectively the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but `multinomial` is faster.

```sh
$ python -m timeit 'import numpy as np' 'np.nonzero(np.random.multinomial(1, [1/6.]*6, size=6))[1]'
50000 loops, best of 5: 4.84 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'import numpy as np' 'np.random.choice(6, size=6, replace=True, p=[1/6.]*6)'
20000 loops, best of 5: 15.9 usec per loop
```

Comment: Depends on the size, for a very large probability distribution (>10k entries) `choice` was faster for me.